# Is it Possible to Get HikariCP Pool Size from Entity Manager?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hikaricp

I've got a JPA EntityManagerFactory that fronts on to a HikariCP connection pool and from it can get an EntityManager, Session, Connection etc. Is there any way I can programmatically find out the max pool size of the Hikari connection pool?

From the debuger, I can see that the Connection object is an instance of a HikariProxyConnection, which has an internal reference to a PoolEntry object, which I assume would link back to the pool which would know the max pool size. But the PoolEntry isn't accessible publicly.

So, given this code:

```
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnitName", new HashMap());
EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
```

And this persistence.xml:

```
    <persistence-unit name="DbNamr">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>...</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.auth" value="Container" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout" value="300000" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="60000" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName" value="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Is there any programmatic way for me to find out that the max pool size is 5?